# Float to Time in java

Tags: java

I have a variable `time = (float)route / (float)speed;` which is 3,96. I wondering if there is some methods to convert this number automatically in to the time? For example 3,96 i need to transform into 4,36.

Comment: Is the result of the operation minutes or hours?

Comment: FYI you could do time = (float)(route/speed); instead of what you have now. Less code ;). If route and speed aren't good old int's.

Comment: The `3,96` result looks good to me - what is the function that you apply to convert `3,96 [some unit]` to `4,36 [other? unit]`?

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus - Not if route and speed are ints!

Comment: @GordonBailey That is true.

Comment: @Xeon no, i just want to get 4,36 from 3,96 without hardcode.

Comment: How is 3,96 converted to 4,36?

Comment: @ShivamKalra I assume it's converting 3 hours, 96 minutes to 4 hours, 36 minutes.

Comment: @Kirix using `float` is a very bad idea because of its (lack of) precision, so another question is: are `route` and `speed` integral values to begin with?

Comment: @Powerlord I wonder how did he even get 3:96 buy simply dividing two floats.

Comment: @fge: to get a time in hours and minutes, a float is precise enough. You might be off by a few micro-seconds, but who cares?

Comment: @JBNizet: given that `0.1` cannot even be represented reliably as a `double`, let alone a `float`, I beg to differ ;)

Comment: So what, you would get 1.0000000001 minutes instead of 1 minute. And you would display it rounded to the closest minute. What would the difference be? By this logic, floating point arithmetic should never be used.

Comment: @JBNizet which is why I asked whether `route` and `speed` were integral values -- with `BigDecimal` and an appropriate rounding mode, you would at least be guaranteed not to lose any precision because of IEEE 754.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the "time" you're getting is not: 3 hours and 96 minutes, but it is really: 3 hours and 0.96 (or 96%) of one hour:

```
            int route = 396; // [km]
            int speed = 100; // [km/h]
            float time = (float) route / (float) speed;
            int hours = (int) time;
            int minutes = (int) (60 * (time - hours));
            System.out.println(hours + "h " + minutes + "m");
```

Output:

```
3h 57m
```